Why doesn't pywinauto click on open on this filedialog?
Context:
I am creating a simple program which clicks 'browse' on a web browser which opens a Filedialog, enters a file I know exists and clicks open.
Problem:
Currently the Program opens the filedialog and enters the filename correctly but is unable to click the 'Open' button.
I noticed that the 'Open' button gets somewhat highlighted or almost 'half clicked' but not actually clicked. Also, If I click 'Open' manually it works. See image for visual context
Visual Context
Code:



import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto.timings import Timings
from pywinauto.findwindows import ElementNotFoundError

def handle_file_dialog(file_path):
    # Increase timing tolerance
    Timings.Slow()

    # Wait for the file dialog to open
    time.sleep(2)

    try:
        # Connect to the dialog window
        app = Application().connect(title_re='Open|Save As')  # Adjust the title based on your OS dialog
        dialog = app.window(title_re='Open|Save As')  # Adjust the title based on your OS dialog
        
        # Wait until the Edit control is ready
        dialog['Edit'].wait('ready', timeout=10)
        
        # Set the file path in the dialog
        dialog['Edit'].set_text(file_path)
        print(f"Set file path: {file_path}")

        # Wait until the Open button is ready and click it
        open_button = dialog.child_window(title_re='&Open|&Open|OK|Save', control_type="Button")
        print(dialog)
        open_button.wait('ready', timeout=10).click()
        print("Clicked the 'Open' button")
    except ElementNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}. The 'Open' button was not found in the dialog.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An unexpected error occurred: {e}")


Desired Output:
For the program to click Open successfully
